# Print content of tables within the HTML code

Tags: php, mysql

Hello friends I have a problem like I print data database I have this code and it works, but I only work within the php code [code]

```
 while ($ row = mysql_fetch_array ($ result)) {
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "Phone", "$ row [phome] </ td> <br>";
             echo "</ tr>"; }
         ////////////////////////////////////////////////// /////
```

I want to print the same contents of the table field phone in my html. I did not run this code and I

`<p> Phone: <? php echo "$ row [phone] </ td> <br>"; ?>` 
[/ code]

I tried

```
 <p> Phone: <? php echo "$ row ['phone'] </ td> <br>"; ?> </ p>
```

try`enter code here`

```
<p> Phone: <? php echo;? "$ row [phone] </ td> <br>." ?> </ p>
```

ofall the possible form

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){` width `foreach(mysql_fetch_array($result) as $row){`

Otherwise, I am not sure what question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have concatenated the value using PHP like this and rephrase your question next time.

```
<p><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></p>
```

Try reading more in here http://www.w3schools.com/php/